# Response 404 by using Axios, but succeed in Postman

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, next.js, axios

In Postman, the link is:

```
http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signin
```

Body:

```
{

    "email":"test1@test1.com",
    "pw":"test1"
}
```

Here is the code in TS:

```
const response = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signin`,
        {
          email: `${username}@${username}.com`,
          pw: password,
        }
      );
```

[image]

Following is the report:[image]

Backend:

```
// CORS on ExpressJS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});

app.use(express.json()); // Allowed come in json data
app.use("/api/users",userRouters)
app.use("/api/dailyPlan",dailyPlanRouters)
app.use("/api/auth",authRouters)

app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    const status=err.status || 500;
    const message = err.message || "Something went wrong";
    return res.status(status).json({
        success:false,
        status,
        message,
    })

})
app.listen(8800,()=>{
    connect();
    console.log("Connected to Server");
})
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: which Nextjs version that you're using ? .and may i see the project structure. you might put wrong folder location in Next.js structure

Comment: can you edit the question and attach a screenshot of your Postman request and response as well?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I solved the problem. It is because CORS problem.